# fields_for -- access access associated model's value and store in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would appreciate your help regarding this:

I have 2 models, book and author, where Book has many Authors and Author belongs to Book

I have the code below which allows user to add multiple authors to book.

```
<% fields_for @book do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :authors do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'author_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Authors", f, :authors %></p>
<% end %>
```

**_author_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.text_field :author_name %>
```

When editing a book entry, I would like to access the author name in the '_author_fields' partial and store it in a variable.

Something like: `<%= author.author_name %>` **this does not work

How do I do that?

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get author in the 'author_fields' form with the local f you are passing:

```
<% author = f.object %>
```

Then you can get the name with author.name